# How do I test the Door lock relay on a Dodge TIPM?

Tags: electrical, dodge, locks, testing

I have a 2011 Dodge Ram.
The drivers door lock switch does not lock the doors.
The passenger door lock switch will lock all doors, including the drivers.
I replaced the drivers door switch with a new part, but had the same result.
Per the diagram I have, the switch goes to the TIPM, through a 25a fuse (tested good), to the "Door Unlock Driver Relay" then to the latch.
I suspect either the relay or the wires.  The relay is soldered into the TIPM. How do I test it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you found the physical location of the relay? If so, testing it is pretty easy. You have a power/ground which switches it, then there are the pass throughs. 87 & 87a will either/or be on, depending on whether the solenoid is energized (I don't remember which). Powering the connection at 86 energizes the circuit. At rest you should see continuity between 30 and 87a. When energized you'll see continuity between 30 and 87. You'll hear it click when you energize the circuit (86 & 86). If you don't have continuity in both (depending on energized or not), your relay is busted and will need replaced.

As a side note, from your diagram, it is a typical relay and will not be hard soldered into the mix. If it is a typical relay, you can easily replace it with another to see if it's working or not ... even one which can be traded out which supports something else (temporarily, of course). You can find these 5-pin relays at almost any automotive parts store.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll throw a tester on it this weekend.